# Ender 3 Microswiss Print Quality Decrease

Tags: creality-ender-3

My Ender 3 was working AMAZING. I decided to buy it a Microswiss All-Metal Hotend. I called the company I bought the printer from, and they sent a technician to install it for me. Once he installed it and left, I started a print on it. The print quality was TERRIBLE. There was stringing everywhere, and the print quality was overall worse. I releveled the bed and tried tuning my slicer settings. I am using PrusaSlicer's default Ender 3 profile with just a few adjustments.

**Start G-code**

```
G90 ; use absolute coordinates
M83 ; extruder relative mode
M104 S[first_layer_temperature] ; set extruder temp
M140 S[first_layer_bed_temperature] ; set bed temp
M190 S[first_layer_bed_temperature] ; wait for bed temp
M109 S[first_layer_temperature] ; wait for extruder temp
G28 ; home all
G1 Z2 F240
G1 X2 Y10 F3000
G1 Z0.28 F240
G92 E0
G1 Y190 E15 F1500 ; intro line
G1 X2.3 F5000
G92 E0
G1 Y10 E15 F1200 ; intro line
G92 E0
```

My retraction settings:

[image: screenshot of PrusaSlicer's retraction settings]

Comment: Stringing can be caused by a variety of reasons.But as you stated, you changed the hotend assembly,I would recommend you to print a temperature tower to see if the printing temperature is too high especially when the thermistor is also replaced.It could have -10~+10 degrees variance between the actual nozzle temp and what is on the screen.

Comment: Extrusion temperature deals with a trade off.  Lowering the temperature reduces stringing, but also reduces layer adhesion.

Comment: What material are you printing? If PLA, then you did not upgrade but sadly downgraded the printer. You need to lower the printing temperature and see if that works. All metal hot ends are for high temperature filaments.

Comment: @0scar thanks.  I only print in PLA.  What do I Do?

Comment: Have you done a PID tune?